# Flagged question as answer: declined!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, declined-flags

Meta-hello!

I flagged an answer where the user actually asked a question as "Not an answer". My flag got declined and I have no idea why.

> not an answer – Cthulhu yesterday   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Here's the complete answer:

> Did you try just to call `[ccController.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];` before your animation block?

I'm not sure if the question is supposed to be rhetorical (my knowledge about the subject is null), but even if it is, shouldn't it be posted as a comment?

I tried to analyze this from different perspectives, but I'm unable to understand how this can be considered a valid answer to the question presented.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670736/animating-uicollectionview-but-cells-disappear/36010230#36010230) is the answer I'm talking about. I would like to clarify this to find if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe people make statements sometimes in the form of a question?

Comment: My issue was that I'm unable to understand if that is a statement or a real question. So, I should have skipped the review instead of flagging.

Comment: Maybe you should skip when you're not sure?  Are you ESL, and maybe don't know about this passive form of making statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm not sure if the question is supposed to be rhetorical (my knowledge about the subject is null), but even if it is, shouldn't it be posted as a comment?

Why should an answer to the question be posted as a comment?  Posting an answer to a question as a rhetorical question is *posting an answer*, not a comment.  It would only need to be a comment if it was actually seeking information from the post author, rather than suggesting a solution.

If it really bothers you, you could edit the answer to be declarative, rather than being a rhetorical question, but it's certainly not a *necessary* change.

Comment: It doesn't bother me, I'm just trying to understand. As I stated on my question, I don't have enough knowledge on the subject to know it the question posted is rhetorical or not. How am I (as reviewer) supposed to know if the user is asking for clarification or posting a solution?

Comment: @Cthulhu If you can't tell, then you should be skipping the post.  You shouldn't just vote to delete a post because you have no idea if it's actually a request for information.  You should *know* that the post is requesting information, rather than suggesting a solution, if you're going to vote to delete it.

Comment: Also, the user that posted the question doesn't even have enough reputation to comment, so he couldn't do it even if he wanted to clarify.

Comment: By the way, according to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer I'm supposed to flag the question as "Not an answer" when someone asks a new question. However, I understand your point and will skip the next time I see something like this.

Comment: @Cthulhu That's referring to someone asking a programming question to which they're expecting to get an answer from someone, instead of posting an answer to the question being asked.  It's not referring to someone posting an answer that happens to contain a grammatical question *in the process of posting an answer*.

Comment: @Cthulhu I declined that flag, Servy has done a great job of explaining why. My litmus test for these is "would this help me if I came in off Google?" - if yes (and it's not link-only), it's an answer.

Comment: @Undo I understand what you are saying. Still, I don't agree, but that happens sometimes. :-) Anyway, if I ever come across this kind of answer again, I will hit the "skip" button. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @Cthulhu. Feel free to ask if you have any questions (or see something I'm missing) :)